# Why does Chrome on Android launch tabs or redirect existing tabs to spammy ads (spontaneously, it seems)?

Tags: chrome-for-android, malware, ads, spam

When using Chrome on my Nexus 6, I often get taken to a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) that causes a modal that reads something like:

> **An embedded page at s3.amazonaws.com says:**
>   Message!
>   Congratulations Grande Communications user, you have been chosen for a chance to get a new iPhone....
>   Click OK to continue

There is no Cancel button. **Why does Google allow developers to launch pop-ups with no cancel button?**

This doesn't occur from clicking on a link. Usually it happens while I'm on a tab, and suddenly another tab will spawn with the modal. I don't think it's caused by a visit to a dubious host, because it's happened when I've had only top sites (Amazon, ebay, etc.) open in the other tabs.

I have run [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/) and a few other security tools and they all say my phone is secure and clean.

What exactly is happening? On the standard Chrome browser, web extensions can rewrite URLs but Chrome for mobile doesn't have web extensions. Could an app intercept network calls from the browser? Could the sites I'm visiting just be serving malicious ads?

Comment: Try clearing the browser cache and see if that repeats?

Comment: Can you do some testing to try to narrow down websites you see it on. I would be surprised if the big guys were hijacked in this way. Are you seeing this over HTTPS?

Comment: Also are you seeing this on Mobile internet or Wifi or both? I.e. if you go and turn off cellular and connect to a 3rd party wifi say Starbucks Wifi - do you see the popup?

Comment: I see this at home over WIFI.

Comment: Neither clearing the browser cache nor deleting suspicious software helped.

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://Andrew.Kvalhe.im/9rJpLhXSD5jraTEefCygGx4V) of this phenomenon that my friend sent me on 2016-07-21. It was tailored correctly to her home ISP—"Congratulations Comcast Cable user, you have been chosen […]". I don't have physical access to the device investigate it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually nothing is malicious or exploit**able** of what you described.

The popup without a cancel button is just a javascript alert. When you press OK nothing happends because you pressed OK. You get redirected because that's simply the next line in the javascript script.

These misleading ads can be blocked with an ad blocking app such as AdAway, although they require root. You could also simply use the Adblock Browser.

Unless you download or install content from such malicious websites you are malware free. Even if they open already installed apps on your phone (Such as Google Play or Gmail) nothing malicious will happen without your consent.

tl;dr
Watch what you allow/install

Answer (score 0):

I found today that it does it on the same site every time I pass it. It must be an ad from that page launching it. As long as you push the back button and ignore it there doesn't seem to be any problem. I do hope they figure out a way to eliminate those ads, it's irritating and a lot people aren't aware enough to just leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Java-script on that Website, I think it will remove the problem.
It is not some sort problem related to virus,it is no-script function which is triggered by java-script when you click on page.